# Mapping tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have the following two tensors:

- **img** is a RGB image of shape (224,224,3)
- **uvs** is a tensor with same spacial size e.g. (224, 224, 2) that maps to coordinates (x,y). In other words it provides (x,y) coordinates for every pixel of the input image.

I want to create now a new output image tensor that contains on index (x,y) the value of the input image. So the output should be an image as well with the pixels rearranged according to the mapping tensor.

Small toy example:

```
img = [[c1,c2], [c3, c4]] where c is a RGB color [r, g, b]
uvs = [[[0,0], [1,1]],[[0,1], [1,0]]]
out = [[c1, c3], [c4, c2]]
```

How would one achieve such a thing in pytorch in a fast vectorized manner?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
out = img[idx[...,0], idx[...,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not really doing what it should do. If I observe correctly your code is selecting the input pixel from the mapping tnesor, while in my setting it should be the opposite, i.e. write the img pixel the the coordinate given by the mapping tensor.

Comment: I guess I know what you want now. It's easier if you can provide a small example of the data.

Comment: I will edit the question, give me some minutes :)

Comment: Please check the example :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it (with the help of Quang Hoang answer)

```
out[idx[...,0], idx[...,1]] = img
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [torch.nn.functional.grid_sample()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html). You can do something like this:

```
width, height, channels = (224, 224, 3)

# Note that the image is channel-first (CHW format). In this example, I'm using a float image, so the values must be in the range (0, 1).
img = torch.rand((channels, height, width))

# Create the indices of shape (224, 224, 2). Any other size would work too.
col_indices = torch.arange(width, dtype=torch.float32)
row_indices = torch.arange(height, dtype=torch.float32)
uvs = torch.stack(torch.meshgrid([col_indices, row_indices]), dim=-1)

# Transform the indices from pixel coordiantes to the to the range [-1, 1] such that:
#   * top-left corner of the input = (-1, -1)
#   * bottom-right corner of the input = (1, 1)
# This is required for grid_sample() to work properly.
uvs[..., 0] = (uvs[..., 0] / width) * 2 - 1
uvs[..., 1] = (uvs[..., 1] / height)* 2 - 1

# Do the "mapping" operation (this does a bilinear interpolation) using `uvs` coordinates.
# Note that grid_sample() requires a batch dimension, so need to use `unsqueeze()`, then
# get rid of it using squeeze().
mapped = torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(
    img.unsqueeze(0),
    uvs.unsqueeze(0),
    mode='bilinear',
    align_corners=True,
)
# The final image is in HWC format.
result = mapped.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0)
```

*Side note: I found your question by searching for a solution for a related problem I had for a while. While I was writing an answer to you question, I realized what bug was causing the the problem I was facing. By helping you I effectively helped my self, so I hope this helps you!*  :)